# Python: filter list based on list

Tags: python, list

I have a list predictions [0, 1, 0 , ....] and a list outcome [ 0, 0, 1, ...]. I want to create a list of all predictions where outcome is 1

I tried:

```
filtered_list = [predictions[i] for i in predictions if outcome[i]==1]
```

Unfortunately that resulted in an empty list.

What am I doing wrong? 
EDIT: I think I fixed it - not sure, as I have not been able to audit the result

```
filtered_list = [i for i in predictions if outcome[i]==1]
```

Comment: This does not fix it. Since `predictions` is a list of 0s and 1s, you are only looking at `outcome[0]` and `outcome[1]`, not the outcome of a prediction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `predictions` and `outcomes` are of the same length, you can use `zip()`

```
[prediction for prediction, outcome in zip(predictions, outcome) if outcome==1]
```

Otherwise, just change `zip()` for the function `zip_longest()` of the `itertools` module.

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate:

```
[i for c,i in enumerate(predictions) if outcome[c]==1]
```

Right now you are indexing by the values and not the indices and that is why it is not working

Answer (score 1):

`i` is an actual prediction, not an index. You need to iterate over the indices to use `i` with both lists.

```
# Working, but meh. See below
filtered_list = [predictions[i] for i in range(len(predictions))
                  if outcome[i] == 1]
```

However, a better solution is to iterate over the elements of both lists in parallel, avoiding indices altogether.

```
filtered_list = [pred for pred, outcome in zip(predictions, outcomes) 
                  if outcome == 1]
```